# Excel C API xlfGetCell with Range

Tags: c++, excel

I'm writing an Excel add-in using c++ and Excel C API, "Excel XLL SDK 2010", and I need to retrieve a range of cells, inside of a command function.
Using the **xlfGetCell** command I can only get the top-left value of the range in an **xltypeStr** XLOPER.

Is there a way to get an **xltypeMulti** XLOPER that would contain the whole range, or do I need to loop on every cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [xlCoerce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/xlcoerce):

```
XLOPER12 xRef, xAddress, xResult;
xAddress.val.str = L"\5A1:C4";
xAddress.xltype = xltypeStr;
Excel12f(xlfIndirect, &xRef, 1, &xAddress);
Excel12f(xlCoerce, &xResult, 1, &xRef);
```

Then `xRef` will contain an xlRef which points to the range A1:C4 on the currently active sheet and `xResult` will contain the xltypeMulti containing the data from that range (which you will need to xlFree).

Unless you are very keen to learn about the fundamentals of the Excel C API, I'd recommend using a wrapper library such as [xlOil](https://gitlab.com/stevecu/xloil), [documentation here](https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xlOil_Cpp/index.html). (Disclaimer: I wrote it).  In xlOil the above would be just

```
auto result = xloil::ExcelRef(L"A1:C4").value();
```